# Determine which variables would increase an expression's value?

Tags: algorithm, logic, expression

In our system, we have expressions defined by the grammar:

```
s ---> e
e ---> (e) | MAX(e, e) | IF(b, e) | IF(b, e, e) | e + e | number | variable
b ---> e | e op e | b AND b | b OR b
op --> > | < | >= | <=
```

where variables are predefined and assigned a value. Each expression has a list of variables e.g.

```
B1 = 4,
B2 = 5,
B5 = 2,
B6 = 2,
C1 = 2,
C4 = 3,
D1 = 2 etc...
```

where the leading letter is the 'group' that the variable falls under. These variables are posed as checkbox "questions" to the user, if they are not selected they have a value of 0 in the expression, otherwise they have the assigned value. It is safe to assume everything in this list is used in the expression.

Our problem: given a set of selected variables, business wants us to give them the set of unselected variables that could be used to increase the value of the expression if selected. For instance, it is common in their expressions to have MAX(B1 + B2 + B3 + C1, 5), and they wouldn't want to show a checkbox for C1 if we already reached a value of 5 with B1 + B2 + B3.

Is there any way to generate this list without trying every combination of selected variables? At a minimum, is there an easy way to generate the list of 'groups' of variables (B, C, D, etc...) that contain at least one variable that would increase the expression value?

In some cases, there are over 150 variables just for one group.

sample expression (they get much larger and more complex than this):

```
IF(B1 AND B2, 6, IF(B1, 2, IF(B2, 2))) + MAX(C1 + C2 + D1, 3) + E1 + E2 + F1 + F2 + F3
```

Comment: I don't understand what "selected" means. If the set of selected variables is given, why would you need to try them all? What exactly is "this list"?

Comment: Why "trying every combination of selected variables"?  Increase every variable while all other variables are non-increased.

Comment: @FalkHüffner the user is shown the list of these variables (they all have associated text), and the user selects which ones apply. If they aren't selected then the value is 0 in the equation

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff this would work except for when they use AND in an expression. If an expression was IF(B1 AND B2, 2) + .... then we would need to select B1 and B2 in order to increase the value